# Do I have to make a deep copy of every parameter in argv callback in SQLITE?

Tags: c, sqlite, callback, copy, memcpy

If I want to store the information returned by the query when calling the callback, should I make a deep copy of every parameter in **argv** or can I safely assume that sqlite3 won't free it after returning from the callback? I'm using C as programming language.

```
static int callback_consult(void *dummy, int argc, char **argv, char **col_name) {
  res_consult_t * answer = &(global_answer -> consult_res);
  movie_t *curr_tuple = calloc(sizeof(char), sizeof(movie_t));

  /* Should I memcpy ??? */
  curr_tuple -> name = argv[0];
  curr_tuple -> genre = argv[1];
  curr_tuple -> description = argv[2];
  curr_tuple -> seats_available = argv[3]; /* Convert to int */

  (answer -> movies)[tuple] = curr_tuple;

  return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Comment: I think I know what you're asking, but the question would be much clearer if you provided sample C code.

Comment: I have just added code @JohnBollinger, that should be clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're asking about what a callback function passed to `sqlite3_exec()` can safely do.

First off, the docs of `sqlite3_exec()` say this:

> The 3rd argument to the sqlite3_exec() callback is an array of pointers to strings obtained as if from sqlite3_column_text(), one for each column. If an element of a result row is NULL then the corresponding string pointer for the sqlite3_exec() callback is a NULL pointer.

Generally speaking, you *do* therefore need to be prepared for result columns to be `NULL`.  Whether it is safe or appropriate to assign such `NULL`s to any particular variable, struct or union member, or array element in your program is a characteristic of your program.  It certainly is not safe to pass `NULL` as an argument to `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`, though, so you may need to account for that.

The docs for `sqlite3_column_text()` get to the meat of the issue, though.  In particular, this applies:

> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically.

Since

> The sqlite3_exec() interface is a convenience wrapper around sqlite3_prepare_v2(), sqlite3_step(), and sqlite3_finalize() [...].

the overall conclusion is that the strings passed into your callback function via argument `argv` are usable only until the callback returns.  If you want to save those results for some kind of later processing then you need to make copies, or in some other way extract the data you need from them.